# Carbon date UTC

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In config/app.php I have the timezone set as follows:

```
 'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Does that mean that any where in my app if I call these carbon methods they will all be UTC or do I still need to add the timezone e.g. carbon::now('UTC')?

```
 carbon::now()
 carbon::today()
 carbon::tomorrow()
```

Comment: Yes, they'll be in UTC. For stuff like this, you may find it easier just trying the commands out in `php artisan tinker` - it's faster than a SO question.

Comment: @ceejayoz many thanks. yes i'll try out tinker

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
$dateUTC = new Carbon("Now UTC");

var_dump($dateUTC);
```

Output (My local Time is 14:01:38):

```
object(Carbon)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2019-11-28 13:01:38"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

or

```
$dateUTC = new Carbon("Now","UTC");
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dateUTC = carbon::now();
```